# Access-Control-Allow-Origin error while creating chrome app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-chrome-app

I am getting  this error  while creating chrome app using angular js :
XMLHttpRequest cannot load chrome-extension://macgkiieglfabdbhlomjjkfaklmgodbi/templates/home.html. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

in index.html i have used this line

```
 <div ui-view class="full-height-footer" id="main-container"></div>
```

which changes the view

In manifest i have specified this :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "abc",
  "version": "2.1",
  "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon_16.png",
    "128": "icon_128.png"
  },
  "app": {
    "background": {
      "scripts": ["main.js"]
    }
  },
  "sandbox": {
    "pages": ["index.html"]
  },
  // "offline_enabled": false,
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://fonts.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'",
  "permissions": [
    "*://fonts.googleapis.com/*",
     "*://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/jb-flashcards/*",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think you're misusing `sandbox` and that results in this error (the sandboxed page won't be able to load other pages). Why do you need to sandbox your file?

Comment: as the page loads a image from server

Comment: I think there are [other solutions](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_external#external) to that.

Comment: but the page contains the image only can be any number of images and image is loading from server